# how to use WebView for show images, video and text as book pages?

Tags: android, pagination, android-webview, ebook-reader

I have a ebook single HTML page having text, video and audios, which I want to display as book pages able to slide left & right to view the previous page and next page respectively.

1. How do I slice the data to show for a particular page for both
   orientations ?
2. I am trying to use WebView for it. Any other possible options?
3. Is HTML is a best way to store the content? Other options?

Comment: Why aren't you go for a native implementation? Using Layouts, Text views, Image views, Buttons etc?

Comment: I have a content from blend text and image like a book. and want to make a viewer for it (ebook reader).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to make an ebook reader you have to consider that the user may not be connected always to internet, so a web view implementation might cause frustration. 
My advice is to go for a native version that download the text/images and act like a real text book reader. Maybe with android animation you can create effects and a nice look :)

Good luck,
Arkde

Comment: What Arkde had said is true, but going the WebView way for ebook is the only way (as of Android 4.0.3) to render complex Indic characters. Other than using WebView component, any other means will display "கி" - a Tamil glyph as "க ி" - as two tamil glyph.